# Laravel's Eager Loading is bringing all data from database

Tags: model, laravel-5, relationship, eager-loading

I have a `Post` model that belongs to a `Category` model. I also have an index page that lists all the `Post`s, and for each one I need to print the name of the `Category` it belongs to.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

My `PostController::index`

```
public function index()
{
    return \View::make('admin/post/index')->with([
        'posts' => \DB::table('posts')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get(),
        'category' => Post::with('category')->get()
    ]);
}
```

Like this, if I echo the `$category`, it shows all registered categories inside of each row in `Post`. I don't know what I can do in the view to show the correct name of the category for each `Post`.

I did this in my view, but like this, it only shows the *x* register of the table for every `Post`:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/admin/post/view/{{ $post->id }}">
                {{ $post->title }}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ str_limit($post->content, 120) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $category[1]->category->category }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ date('m/d/Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/admin/post/edit/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                Edit
            </a>
            <a href="/admin/post/delete/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

How do I properly print the name of the `Category`, which is related to `Post`, with Laravel 5.2 using Eager Loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below steps can help you.
In model you make a relation with catefory like below:

```
class Post extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'category_id'
 ];

  //Relation with category Model category table
 public function relCategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
 }
}
```

After that you get all data in controller from Post model like below:

```
public function index()
{
  return \View::make('admin/post/index')->with([
    'data' => App\Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()
  ]);
}
```

Now in view page you can call the model relation and view category like below:

```
@foreach($data as $values)
  <td>
     {{ $values->relCategory->category }}
  </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved it. What's the difference between using `\DB::table('posts')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()` and your solution?

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes ... when you use DB:: it process direct query .. but when you use Model .. then query at first transfer in Model then process SQL query.. In your case i use Post Model, so that i can access the relCategory method inside this Post model ...

Comment: I see. Thank you for your solution.